# How do I find how many persons their lastname ends with a specific letter?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, find

I am trying to find from a text file how many lastnames end with "on". I tried the following:

```
awk '$2 == "^.on$" {count++} END{print count}' students
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It just printing out a blank line. Any ideas?. Thank you.

Comment: Just use `on$` as the regex, no need for `^.`. `^` anchors to the start of the string and `.` matches one character, so at the moment your regex matches `con`, `son`,`won`, etc.

Comment: Still nothing. I think the problem might be the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match `regex` you should not use  equals sign like `$2 == "^.on$"`. rather use ~ for regex match.

```
awk '$2 ~ /on$/{count++}END{print count}' students
```

This will match last two chars of second column of the file.